# Is there an easy way to provoke soft errors?

Tags: test

So I'm mainly involved in writing firmware for industrial sensors which are expected to be very robust.

One of the things you have to face are random errors everywhere, especially in ICs outside of the microcontroller. What we usually do is cyclic initialization so we are sure that the volatile registers are written inside a certain time, if possible with every cycle. That way we are pretty safe against soft errors harming us a long time.

Some ICs have a bit of a problem with that method so for those we switch to a read - check - correct method. We read the registers, check them against what is expected and if it doesn't match we correct the registers.

Testing this method proves to be a bit difficult. Sure we can modify the value we read in the firmware and check whether the correcting measures are done correctly, but I'd like to see that we actually capture soft errors in the device.

**TL;DR**
Sometimes we are "lucky" that during our EMI tests a soft error happens in the IC we would like to test, but is there a relatively easy way to provoke soft errors in a specific IC on a PCB?

Comment: Alpha particle beams are the standard method to induce faults, if I recall. The general topic is 'alpha particle induced fault injection' or something like that. They can be made energetic enough to penetrate into the epoxy (beta won't do it) while being relatively safe and easy to block, otherwise.

Comment: Gamma rays? X-rays? Neither are the sorts of sources you'd want lying around in the lab. I've no idea what sort of regulatory hoops you'd need to jump through and training you'd need to be able to get (let's say) a low-level gamma emitter in a lead box, but I can't imagine it would be easy. Maybe there are facilities that can do this sort of thing. I used to have to go to 3rd party facilities for low pressure environmental testing for instance.

Comment: @jonk I was kinda assuming alpha wouldn't cut it, what with their small penetration depth and all, but of course they pack a punch in what they do land in. Obviously much safer than gamma and X.

Comment: @Neil_UK Found this: "Alpha Particle-Induced Soft Errors in Microelectronic Devices," 1980ish. They write in the abstract, "The process of an alpha particle penetrating an IC is examined." Alphas are in solder, the packaging itself, and so on. So circuits are exposed. But I agree with you and plead my general ignorance here. Apparently, these techniques are considered a standard. I know that the cross-section (probability) will depend on energy, so there may be "windows" of opportunity. But I'd actually be interested in reading more. I hate gamma -- lead looks like vacuum to it.

Comment: You could provoke noise on the data line you are using to communicate with these ICs. Say they are connected to an SPI bus - you could intentionally add clock jitter or data noise to the bus. Also noise to power supply could cause some brown-out states. Since it's an industrial setting, this could be the most relevant error source. Like others mentioned, radiation bit-shift is also a possibility, mainly seen in research for spacial or aerial applications.

Comment: @jonk I think that was more focussed on radioactive contaminants in the construction of the IC itself, but it's a long time since I read (probably the same sort of) articles. My understanding was that alphas had a very short and well defined penetration depth in dense materials (like the dead outer layer of skin, which contributes to their safety), specifically because they are so efficient at depositing energy in it.

Comment: @Neil_UK The article I mentioned wasn't about the testing I'm separately aware of. I worked with some researchers from IBM who mentioned the testing, in general terms. There is actually a "fault injection" purpose. Not accidental. Still, I agree with you about alpha. As a child I was told a piece of paper would stop them. So yeah. I didn't grill the researchers at the time. I slightly regret that, now.

Comment: Thank you all for the input so far, good keywords coming up for further research. But I get the impression, the answer is close to no, there is no easy way.